# Eggplant - Read dynamic text on the device

Tags: eggplant

Starting from the top of the device, I have 3 individual lines of text which changes per user who is logged in. I wish to capture and read the image on line 3. There is on more line of text on the 4th line which is static text i.e. will always remain same regardless of the user. Assume the text is place as below:

```
Dynamic user based text line 1
Dynamic user based text line 2
Dynamic user based text line 3
Hello World (Static text)
```

I am writing a method which could return "Dynamic user based text line 3". To read that line, I cannot pass in the co-ordinates since it would differ based on the device screen size. Not sure if there is a way in Eggplant to read lines above "Hello World" by passing in static text as "Hello World".

One way I tried doing this is based on the placement of the "Dynamic user based text line 3" i.e. I tried calculating a ratio using x and y coordinates of "Dynamic user based text line 3" with regards to the screen width and height, but even this doesn't work in case of different device. Below is the code:

```
Connect(myDevice)
LaunchApp "myApp"
put RemoteScreenSize().x into xCoordinates
put RemoteScreenSize().y into yCoordinates
put ReadText((xCoordinates * 7/180, yCoordinates * 5/38), (multiline: yes))
```

Is there a way to read such a dynamic text using Eggplant?

Answer (score 0):

If Hello World is a static text, by taking this as a reference we can build a search rectangle to get "Dynamic user based text line 3"